# Uploading images/file in Django in production mode

Tags: django, filefield

I am a noob in Django and I am about to deploy my first site in Django. I have a Profile model in my models.py file which has profile_pic attribute which will store the profile pic of the user. It is working well when upload the image in the development mode,ie, when DEBUG=True. But what changes do I have to make in the urls.py so that users can easily upload their profile picture even after deploying my site. Any code snippetor examples or some link would be very helpful.